# PHP for loop generating the radio buttons and I want just one selected from those buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, radio-button

I have this for loop and I want just one radio button to be selected from all of this 99.

```
            for($x = 2; $x <= 101; $x++){
                $out .= "<img src='/img/channel_icons/".$icons[$x]."' class='channel-icons' title='".$icons[$x]."' alt='".$icons[$x]."' width='20px' height='20px' >";
                $out .= "<input type='radio' value='icon'>";
            }
```

I can select multiple radio buttons, but I want to enable user to select just one of them.
Could anyone help me with this ? Could I do this using radio buttons or I need to use something else ? Checkboxes ? Could I do this without using javascript or I have to use it ?

Newbie in frontEnd stuff.

Comment: if you name your radio, they should be able to select only the one, given a unique name, or id if using js; thinking out loud here (for the js method).

Comment: check my solution is useful for you

Comment: Is my answer is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add name of the radio button to group these button

```
for($x = 2; $x <= 101; $x++){
            $out .= "<img src='/img/channel_icons/".$icons[$x]."' class='channel-icons' title='".$icons[$x]."' alt='".$icons[$x]."' width='20px' height='20px' >";
            $out .= "<input type='radio' value='icon' name='sample'>";
        }
```

Comment: Really nice and easy solution.. Thanks.